Data Rate and Frequency. Who defines the frequency range?
I understand that higher frequencies lead to faster data rates, but this is not due to the value of the frequency itself. Rather, it’s because of the increased bandwidth available at those higher frequencies.
From this previous answer by Bimpelrekkie, the key factor appears to be the ability to "extract" as many 100 MHz blocks (or any defined unit) as possible from the total available bandwidth within the frequency range. In other words, the crucial aspect is the bandwidth—the difference between the lower and upper limits of the frequency range—rather than the central frequency alone.
However, I often hear frequency values expressed as single points, such as "800 MHz" (for 4G LTE) or "2.4 GHz." Is there a convention for how these ranges are defined or expressed? Does the mentioned frequency represent the center of a band, or is it indicative of something else?
What are the standards regarding the ranges around the central frequency? Who decides this? Is it determined by an international standard, or is it regulated by governments that auction off portions of the spectrum?
Additionally, something I don’t fully understand is: when we transitioned from 3G to 4G, we moved from 2100 MHz (for 3G) to a lower frequency (800 MHz) for 4G, yet we saw an improvement in speed. Doesn’t this contradict the idea that higher frequencies offer faster speeds?

The 2.4 GHz in WiFi refers to the radio frequency being used. It's unrelated to the data rate and "frequency" you're referring to (which is really the bandwidth or symbol rate).

Let's start with the simple case. Non-RF - signals that are sent through wires rather than the air.
An LVDS data bus can achieve Gbps data rates, yet has a carrier frequency of DC (0Hz), because it has a huge bandwidth to play with - limited only by the losses in the conductive wires it's fed through. Strictly speaking the signal requires an infinite bandwidth to sent, though we can get away with less.
For RF however, it is not possible to transmit with infinite bandwidths, because you need to propagate the signal via radio waves. Using very low frequencies requires huge antennae, which would be extremely poor at transmitting higher frequencies, and vice versa.
To get around this, RF signals are mixed in some fashion onto a carrier signal. There are many different techniques for this (AM, FM, OOK, FSK, OFDM, etc.), but the common theme is the baseband signals are shifted up in the frequency domain to some carrier (sometimes multiple carriers).
Generally speaking, the higher the carrier frequency, the more bandwidth you have to play with. Remember that you physically can't go down to DC, so your bandwidth is strictly less than twice the centre frequency. In reality, its not possible to get anywhere near that bandwidth - antennas don't have that much bandwidth capability, and other people want to use the same radio spectrum too.
Once you get up to several hundreds of MHz or GHz, the centre frequency stops having much to do with bandwidth anymore. A 2.4GHz Wi-Fi channel might only have a bandwidth of 20MHz. Any 800MHz 4G LTE channel can also have a 20MHz bandwidth allocated. A 2.4GHz BLE channel has only 2MHz bandwidth allocated. The centre frequency is essentially only selected due to regulatory requirements (remember other people want to use the spectrum) which specify who is allocated what chunk of the spectrum for a given purpose.
Instead the data rate becomes much more dependent on how you make use of the bandwidth you have available, along with how much physical space and power you have to play with which governs your signal strengths. Different technologies (4G, 5G, WiFi, etc.) use different techniques to get the most out of their allocation. With DSP technology getting smaller and less power hungry, newer standards can sent data at faster rates (or lower power) using more and more complex techniques.

As a side note, you will note that the Shannon-Hartley theorem:
$$C = B\log_2\left(1 + \frac{S}{N}\right)$$
Which postulates the maximum theoretically possible data rate for a channel \$C\$, is dependent only on the bandwidth \$B\$ and signal to noise ratio \$\frac{S}{N}\$. It doesn't depend on the carrier frequency used, purely the bandwidth of the channel.
